# How do I generate txt files into separate directories with python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, directory, with-statement

**This is my code**

```py
import os

pwd = os.getcwd()

playlist_links = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',]

for link in playlist_links:
    # Create the path
    path = os.path.join(pwd, link)

    # Create the directory
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)

    os.chdir(path)

    with open("Z:/www.rttv.com/Change_Into_Dir_TEST/single-video-v5-{}.txt".format(link), 'w', encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        output_file.write(link)

    os.chdir(pwd)
```

**This is the output I get:**

[image]

What I want is to have each txt file in its respected folder. For example:

*single-video-v5-A.txt should be in the A folder*

*single-video-v5-B.txt should be in the B folder*

*single-video-v5-C.txt should be in the C folder*

And so on and so forth...
What exactly is wrong with my code?

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't include the placeholder as folder in the path, instead you put it at the end of your filename...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look toward this logic, changes are subtle but effect is crucial:

```
import os
pwd = os.getcwd()
playlist_links = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',]

for link in playlist_links:
    path = os.path.join(pwd, link)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    
    with open(f"single-video-v5-{link}.txt", 'w', encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        output_file.write(link)
    
    os.chdir(pwd)
```

After the execution, checking the contents of the current working directory, then the contents of the A/ directory:

```
$ ls
A  B  C  D  E  F  p.py
$ ls A/
single-video-v5-A.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

it might help

```
import os

pwd = os.getcwd()

playlist_links = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',]

for link in playlist_links:
    # Create the path
    path = os.path.join(pwd, link)

    # Create the directory
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)

    save_file = f'single-video-v5-{link}.txt' # create the file name
    save_path = os.path.join(path,save_file)  # create the save_path using above file name

    # open the file write it and close
    with open(save_path, 'w', encoding="utf8") as out_file:
        out_file.write(link)
```

i dont see any need for calling os.chdir()

[image]